# How do I prioritize results that I pass in?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I have the following bool query:

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "term" : { "title" : "technology" }
      },
      "should" : [
        { "term" : { "text" : "companies that produce hardware" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Suppose this returns the following document id's (in order):

```
1. netflix
2. google
3. microsoft
4. dell
5. intel
```

Before this query happens I query a separate database and get the following results (in order):

```
1. intel
2. amazon
3. dell
```

I'd like to prioritize the results of my database over those of elasticsearch so that I get the following results:

```
1. intel
2. dell
3. netflix
4. google
5. microsoft
```

(Notice that amazon doesn't show up since we're not trying to create an elasticsearch document out of thin air).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [script based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting), which allows you to sort your data based on a custom script.

Use a script that assigns a priority value for each result.
Could be something like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "term" : { "title" : "technology" }
      },
      "should" : [
        { "term" : { "text" : "companies that produce hardware" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "order": "asc",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "if (doc['company'].value.equals('intel')) return 0;
                   else if (doc['company'].value.equals('amazon')) return 1;                          
                   else if (doc['company'].value.equals('dell')) return 2;                          
                   else return 3;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I used `company` field since sorting on the '_id' field is discouraged, even though it's possible. Check out [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html).

For more infomation, check [Sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html), [Scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) and [Painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-painless.html).

Hope it helps!

Comment: what is switch? what is "company"? can I use "id" instead or is there a catch?

Comment: the "else return 3" will that leave the rest of the docs untouched? eg doesn't mess up the sorting of the remaining docs?

Comment: @MarissaLevy Nevermind, I removed the 'switch statement' part from my answer.
This script won't change any of your documents content, and will only affect the sorting of your results in this particular query. I've added a link to ES sorting documentation.
"else return 3" guarantees that if a document doesn't fit in any of the 'if statement', its priority value will be the highest and it will be placed at the end.
Added info about the '_id' field as well :)